# source env/bin/activate 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, django

venv) C:\Users\Sunil\PycharmProjects\project>source env/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
venv) C:\Users\Sunil\PycharmProjects\project>source env/bin/activate
```

Comment: Source is a *nix command, but apparently this is a Windows shell. I'm not sure if they know what `source` means.

Comment: On Windows, there is a `.bat` file, just *run* that.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows environment you'll need to look for an `activate.bat` file - typically in the same folder as `activate` which is for *nix systems.